# Are there any denominations that are or have been both continuationist and non-Trinitarian?

Tags: church-history, denomination-survey, non-trinitarian, continuationism

Are there any denominations currently or throughout the history of Christianity that are or have been both **continuationist** and **non-Trinitarian**?

Comment: Oneness Pentecostalism is obvious, right?

Comment: @curiousdannii - Right. Latter-day Saints are another example. Are there / have there been any others?